# WordPress is getting 404 with non-English filenames

Tags: uploads

I have an old WordPress site. The site is now running on WP 6.2.2 with the TwentyFifteen theme. PHP version is 8.1.20 with no major Alert in WP Health page.

If you open the file on a new tab, it's getting 404:
`/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/বাংলা-নমুনা-লেখা-bangla-name-generator-mayeenul-islam.png` (Bengali)
`/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Écoquartier_vauban_freibourg1.jpg` (Non-English)

But I can confirm the files are there.

I tried regenerating the thumbnails, but only the non-English files are skipped saying they don't exist. But I can confirm the files are already there.

[image: thumbnails regeneration skipped]

What I tried so far:

1. Disabling all the Plugins
2. I refreshed the Permalinks.

Is this a bug in WP 6.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your database `collation` to `utf8_general_ci`?
If not, the Unicode characters might not work.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. db collation are utf8_general_ci and some plugins created tables with utf8mb4_general_ci. BTW good point, but that didn't solve the issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

The earlier observation showed that the files were there with their exact names. But later (2023-Jul-23) found that the files were being renamed by a spam attack into some gibberish names with Russian scripts.

[image: gibberish file names]

As the file names were changed, it's obvious that the files cannot be found (404).

To resolve this,

1. I had to find the original file name from the URL stored in the database (which can be grabbed from the Media Library), and renamed the files in the file system
2. I deleted all the gibberish versions of that particular original from the path
3. Using the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin, I deleted all the versions and regenerated the files from scratch